# P4 Simple switch for linking two VMs

Tags: p4-lang

I am trying to link two virtual machines via P4 simple switch. I use `simple_router.json` taken from the P4 repository on github.
I managed to `ping` from one host to another, but if I use the `iperf` command, the TCP connection is not established.

What could be the problem and what am I doing wrong?

I used the same MAC and IP address settings for the VMs and the same commands for the switch. However, when emulating in `mininet`, everything works.